# Finding torsion coefficients for $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_9$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> The part of the decomposition theorem $11.12$ corresponding to the
>   subgroups of prime power order can also be written in the form
>
> $\mathbb{Z}_{m_1}\times \mathbb{Z}_{m_2}\times \cdots \times
>  \mathbb{Z}_m$, where $m_i$ divides $m_{i+1}$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,r-1$
>
> The numbers $m_i$ can be shown to be unique, and are the torsion
>   coefficients of $G$

-Find the torsion coefficents of $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_9$

The theorem $11.12$ is concerned about a finitely generated abelian group being isomorphic to

$$\mathbb{Z}_{(p_1)^{r_1}}\times \mathbb{Z}_{(p_2)^{r_2}}\times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_{(p_n)^{r_n}}\times \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}$$

How can I represent $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_9$ in the form $\mathbb{Z}_{m_1}\times \mathbb{Z}_{m_2}\times \cdots \times
 \mathbb{Z}_m$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(4,9)=1$, $\Bbb{Z}_4\times \Bbb{Z}_9\cong \Bbb{Z}_{36}$ and also $\Bbb{Z}_4$ and $\Bbb{Z}_9$ cannot be decomposed into cyclic factors of smaller size.
Hence $36$ is the torsion coefficient.

**Theorem:**

> $(m,n)=1$ iff $\Bbb{Z}_m\times \Bbb{Z}_n\cong \Bbb{Z}_{mn}$

Remark:
The torsion coefficient is commonly known as *invariant factor*. You can try to refer Abstract Algebra, Dummit & Foote, Section 5.2 for more informations about this.

Comment: More generally, $\mathbb{Z}_m\oplus \mathbb{Z}_n \cong \mathbb{Z}_d\oplus \mathbb{Z}_l$ where $d=gcd(m,n), l=lcm(m,n)$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205618/abstract-algebra.