# $R/(a) \oplus R/(b) \cong R/\gcd(a,b) \oplus R/\operatorname{lcm}(a,b) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

> Let $R$ be a PID. How can one show that for all non zero $a,b \in R$ we have $R/(a) \oplus R/(b) \cong R/\gcd(a,b) \oplus R/\operatorname{lcm}(a,b) $.

I have no idea how to define such an isomorphism. What I tried is to define $f([x],[y])=([\gcd(x,y)], [\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)])$. I didn't get anywhere with that my map is probably not even well defined I got lost in the calculations. So does anyone know how to find the desired isomorphism.

Thanks in advance

Comment: HINT: when $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then the statement is simply the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Now, since every PID is a UFD, use prime factorizarion and apply Chinese Remainder Theorem to conclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the exact sequence $0\rightarrow S\rightarrow R^{2}\rightarrow V\rightarrow 0.$ Write the canonical basis of $R^{2}$ as $e_{1},e_{2}$, the generators of $S$ as $\{f_{1},f_{2}\}$.

Let $(f_{1},f_{2})=(e_{1},e_{2})
\left(\begin{matrix}
a&0\\
0&b
\end{matrix}\right)$, then $V=R/(a)\oplus R/(b).$

The Smith Normal Form of
$\left(\begin{matrix}
a&0\\
0&b
\end{matrix}\right)$ is
$\left(\begin{matrix}
\gcd(a,b)&0\\
0&\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)
\end{matrix}\right)$ (it can be achieved by multiplying on the left and right by invertible square matrices), so we have:

$$R/(a)\oplus R/(b)\cong V\cong R/(\gcd(a,b))\oplus R/(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)).$$

Comment: For an explicit computation, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2226275/589.