# Proving additive is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove additive group Z6 × Z25 × Z49 is cyclic. 
Just need to know exact steps of how I should think about this question, what properties if the groups should I be focusing on.

Comment: Hint: Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proving that $\mathbb{Z}_m\oplus \mathbb{Z}_n \cong \mathbb{Z}_d\oplus \mathbb{Z}_l $ as groups, where $l=lcm(m,n$) and $d=gcd(m,n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205618/proving-that-mathbbz-m-oplus-mathbbz-n-cong-mathbbz-d-oplus-mathbbz)

Answer (score 1):

The order of element $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ in group $A_1
\times A_2 \dots A_n$ is the lcm of the orders of the $a_i$.

If these orders are coprime then the order of the element is the product of the orders.

In our example we can find an element of order $6\times 25\times 49$ so it is cyclic.

---

In general one has a product of cyclic groups is cyclic if and only if the orders are coprime.